# Best way to reorder code execution based on condition

Tags: php, architecture

I have two blocks of PHP code: BlockA and BlockB (a block is just a couple of code lines, typically 10 lines or more.). Based on the situation, I may need to run BlockA before BlockB or BlockB before BlockA. I have been doing it in two ways up till now, but I was wondering if there is some advanced technique to handle this situation.

**Method 1:**

```
if(some condition)
{
      BlockA;
      BlockB;
}
else
{
     BlockB;
     BlockA;
}
```

This is very ugly because I have to repeat some 50 lines of code twice and any change has to be done two times (imagine if I had five blocks to be ordered).

**Method 2:**
Create a function for each block.

```
if(some condition)
{
      BlockA();
      BlockB();
}
else
{
     BlockB();
     BlockA();
}
```

This solves the problem of repetitive code but seems a little bit strange to create functions just because you want to reorder a piece of code. How do the professionals handle this situation? The situation could become even more complex if there were let's say 10 blocks to order.

Comment: Without more information about what the code does, who can say.  It may be preferable to bake the condition into the function, it's too abstract to really know.

Comment: it does not really matter what the code does, the only thing to note here is that all the statements in each block are executed as a unit and in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Professionals absolutely create functions.  It's not uncommon to make a function out of a single line of code.  The idea is that it makes your code more readable.  It's well worth reading up on [Clean Code](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-write-clean-code-lessons-learnt-from-the-clean-code-robert-c-martin-9ffc7aef870c).

Ideally your functions SHOULD be small, less than 10 lines of code, and never more than a page.  Now, PHP does a fairly poor job of handling functions, and there is a non-zero overhead to doing a function call (15% or so), but it's rare that you are writing an application that is CPU intensive in PHP (if you are, please don't, it's the wrong tool for the job).